# Запросы типа LIKE в библиотеке aura sql query

Tags: php

Ребята, кто-нибудь сталкивался с LIKE запросами в библиотеке aura/sqlquery?
https://packagist.org/packages/aura/sqlquery

Не соображу, как составить такой запрос, используя их функции.

Если просто писать на PDO. А в aura/sqlquery как?

```
public function search($table, $search) {

    $stm  = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE title LIKE ? OR content LIKE ?");
    $params = array("%$search%", "%$search%");
    $stm->execute($params);
    $data = $stm->fetchAll();
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Последнее обновление ветки `dev` было аж в 2017 году, он вам точно нужен?

Comment: судя по [документации](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.SqlQuery/blob/a4fd8dc4493d517ef3d06e1dbb9433c81fff16ce/docs/select.md) как-то так `$sql = $factory->newSelect()->cols(['id', 'title'])->from($table)->where([tilte LIKE :t])->orWhere('content like :c')->getStatement()` и потом передаете это в PDO `$st = $pdo->prepare($sql); $st->execute(['t' => ..., 'c' => ...])`;

Comment: Пасиб! Знак получилось.